# can springRepository wait for a sql insert trigger to return a value?

Tags: spring, postgresql, triggers, insert, spring-data

I got a trigger on database level that do some logic and returns a integer every time a row is inserted. This value is to fill a field at that table.

Every time I save my entity, the trigger is fired and everything works great. But i need that value at my spring repository level.

After I have saved my entity, some place later in that code, I do a findById at this same row (in the same transaction) and this value inserted by the trigger still null.

If I do a findById in another transactions the value returns.

How can I get obtain this value inserted by the trigger at java application level?

I've tried saveAndFlush / flush after it has saved the entity, but doesn't 
work.

Any ideas how to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Would implementing logic in a @PostPersist method, either to do what the trigger is doing, or working with the trigger generated value, do the trick ?

Comment: Yeah, probably i would go for that line. Migrate that trigger to spring level... Thanks for the tips =)